# Node index.js command is keep ignored in window powershell

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run index.js in localhost.
So, I make index.js like this.

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.end('Hello');
}).listen(3000, ()=> {
  console.log('running');
})
```

I typed `node index.js` but there is nothing in the console and it just turns off by itself.

There is nothing on console.

[image]

like this.

I typed that thing at PowerShell and git bash but none of them works.

I tried another port like 8080 or 8000 but it's not working.
And I also used `forever`, `pm2`, and `nodemon` but it doesn't work, too.

I think it's something like a firewall problem.
But I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: `node --version` gives you what result? try also adding more `console.log` to see if it actually runs

Comment: @ShaharHadas When I typed node --version at git and powershell, It gaves me v12.2.0.

Comment: For me the above code is working fine. Something is not right with your environment or machine

Answer (score 0):

Try to break your code.

It might be because your code does not hold the instance of the server, it clear itself ... hence the listen promise isn't even reached.

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.end('Hello');
})

server.listen(3000, ()=> {
  console.log('running');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
## Try below code please
var http = require('http');

//create a server object:
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
  res.end(); //end the response
}).listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
```